# Removing levels from data frame read from CSV file - R

Tags: string, r, dataframe

I tried loading the baseball statistics from [this](http://baseballguru.com/MLB2011.xls) link. When I read it from the file using

```
data <- read.csv("MLB2011.csv")
```

it seems to be reading all fields as factor values. I tried dropping those factor values by doing:

```
read.csv("MLB2011.xls", as.is= FALSE)
```

.. but it looks like the values are still being read as factors. What can I do to have them loaded as simple character values and not factors?

Comment: You are using `read.csv` to open a file which appears to be an excel spreadsheet, not a `csv` (if you are using the linked file as is)

Comment: Check out this [video link](http://www.screenr.com/QiN8) on reading excel files into R.

Comment: I am sorry for the miscommunication. I had converted the excel sheet to csv before doing `read.csv()`

Comment: In that case, you want `as.is = TRUE` or `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: and now added to my answer

Comment: I would suggest searching for the word "factor" in the `?read.csv` page.  See if any arguments look useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You aren't reading a `csv` file, it is an excel spreadsheet (.xls format). It contains two worksheets `bat2011` and `pitch2011`

You could use the `XLConnect` library to read this

```
library(XLConnect)
# load the work book (connect to the file)
wb <- loadWorkbook("MLB2011.xls")


# read in the data from the bat2011 sheet
bat2011 <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = 'bat2011')
```

`readWorksheet` has an argument `colType` which you could use to specify the column types.

---

Edit

If you have already saved the sheets as csv files then

`as.is = TRUE` or `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` will be the correct argument values

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. But I had converted the excel sheet to csv before doing read.csv(). I wrote the question in a hurry