# removing levels from dataframe failed

Tags: r

I am trying to do calculations on a dataframe column but they keep failing because the column contains levels despite my having used the droplevels command (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762808/removing-levels-from-data-frame-read-from-csv-file-r) post). What am I doing wrong here:

```
csv <- data.frame(col1 = c("question",1,23,2,5,6), col2 = c("question",5,6,7,3,""))
csv[csv==''] <- NA
csv <- csv[-c(1),] #remove the header question row because this screws up numeric calculations
csv <- droplevels(csv)
csv[,1] <- 7-csv[,1]
```

I get:

```
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(7, csv[, 1]) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dropping levels is a different kind of command. You no longer want factors. Try `as.numeric(as.character(mycol))` to prepare the column for arithmetic.

```
csv[] <- lapply(csv, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

I wrapped it in `lapply` to convert all columns.

Result:

```
csv[,1] <- 7-csv[,1]
  col1 col2
2    6    5
3  -16    6
4    5    7
5    2    3
6    1   NA
```

---

We drop levels when we have unused factors. Not to convert them to numbers. Example:

```
fac <- factor(c("a", "b")) #factor with two levels 'a' and 'b'
fac
#[1] a b
#Levels: a b

fac.one <- fac[1] #Just the first element of 'fac' which is 'a'.
fac.one
#[1] a
#Levels: a b       # <-- There are still two levels. 'b' is not used.
```

When we made `fac.one`, we have only one element. But the old factor levels remain. If we only want the factors that are being used in the object, we use `droplevels` like so:

```
droplevels(fac.one)
#[1] a
#Levels: a     #One factor remains. 'b' is dropped
```